# "Ubuntu One" authentication Failure in Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, authentication

I just updated the Ubuntu One client on my Windows 7 machine today.  When I try to sign in, I receive the "authentication failed" error message, even though the same credentials work on the Ubuntu One website and my Ubuntu 11 machine at work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be authentication bugs in the latest windows client for ubuntu one. Download earlier version from http://one.ubuntu.com/windows/ubuntuone-2.0.3-windows-installer.exe and install it.

It should work and check for the change-logs in the future releases and updates for this bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem validating the SSL certificate in some cases. Could you try the latest version (4.0.0) and see if that fixes it for you?